# How to replace a line in a file on multiple computers using PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, connection

I'm trying to replace one line in a test.ini file on multiple PCs with Powershell.
But I need to replace this line in a test.ini file with different content.
For example:

- PC st1: in test.ini file line 10 I have "hello" and I need to replace
  that with "hi"
- PC st2: in test.ini file line 10 I have "hello" and I need to replace
  that with "bye"

I created a script but don't understand how can I change the same line with different content on multiple PCs (

```
$devices = Get-Content "C:\script\device.txt"

foreach ($computer in $devices) {
  Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer -scriptblock {
    ((Get-Content -path C:\test\test.ini -Raw) -replace 'hello','world') | Set-Content -Path C:\test\test.ini
    Get-Content -path C:\test\test.ini | Select -Index 10
  }
}
```

Please help if I can do that perhaps.

Comment: Hi, you can use a CSV file as an input.. with computername,findword, replaceword. Loop and Pass the arguments of findword and replaceword in invoke-command.

Comment: What's the pattern? Every 2nd PC gets "bye" instead of "hi"?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen, not every second PC, I have to do that change on approximate 50 PCs

Comment: @user2670623, can you do an example please, I'm a novice in Powershell

Comment: @OlegKaisin Right, but how do you know which 50 PCs need to be updated, and which ones needs "bye" vs "hi"? Do you have two lists?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen no I have one excel file, where I have PC name and what kind of parameter that must have.

Comment: It is also quite dangerous to change word in an ini file like that. Than file could have many occurrences of `hello`, both as property Name and property Value. To update structured data, better use a dedicated module like [PsIni](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PsIni/3.1.2).

Comment: @Theo, each PC has a unique parameter, I want to change only that parameter if you understand what I mean. "hello" I use for an example

Comment: @OlegKaisin No, sorry I don't understand what you mean.. Are you talking about some part of the computer's Name perhaps?  Please provide info on that in the question itself, not as a comment.

Comment: @Theo sorry, I didn't mean to offend you, I'm just trying to explain correctly so that we can understand each other

Comment: No offence taken. It's just that you speak of _"a unique parameter"_ but in the code you show there is no mention of any parameter whatsoever.. Please provide more info about this, maybe show us some of your `device.txt` file so we can understand what that parameter might be.

Comment: Yes, we know, but remember we cannot see your screen, so it's a mystery still what that 'parameter' is.. Do you keep a list of which pc needs to have value 'hi' and which pc needs to get 'bye'? Is there some logic we can deduce that from the computers name perhaps? Without knowing that, this question simply cannot be answered I'm afraid

Comment: @Theo, in this `device.txt` I have a list of PCs.
Example of what is inside of that `txt`: C2712, C1278, C2452,....
And each of that PC has a `.ini` file 
Inside of `.ini` file I need to change one line doesn't matter is that a parameter or not I need just change that line.
**That is inside of  .ini**
`ClientID=c2721
ServerIPAddress=
ServerPort=
ListenerPort=
Application=
Language=`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so here's what I mean.

Instead of the text file with just the computer names in it, make that a CSV file like [user2670623](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69644573/how-to-replace-a-line-in-a-file-on-multiple-computers-using-powershell?noredirect=1#comment123101106_69644573) already commented

```
ComputerName,SearchWord,Replacement
C2712,hello,hi
C1278,hello,bye
C2452,hello,again
```

Now you have the computer name, the search word AND the replacement for that particular computer all in one and then you can do stuff like this:

```
$devices = Import-Csv "C:\script\device.csv"

foreach ($computer in $devices) {
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer.ComputerName -ScriptBlock {
        param(
            [string]$findThis,
            [string]$replaceWith
        )
        # -replace uses regex, so the $findThis string needs to be escaped because it may or may not
        # contain characters that have special meaning in Regular Expressions.
        (Get-Content -Path 'C:\test\test.ini' -Raw) -replace [regex]::Escape($findThis), $replaceWith | Set-Content -Path 'C:\test\test.ini'
    } -ArgumentList $computer.SearchWord $computer.Replacement
}
```

If it is not possible to create the CSV file for some reason, then you're stuck with tedious code like

```
$devices = Get-Content "C:\script\device.txt"

foreach ($computer in $devices) {
    # for each computer, define what is to be replaced by what
    switch ($computer) {
        'C2712' { $find = 'hello'; $replace = 'hi' }
        'C1278' { $find = 'hello'; $replace = 'bye' }
        'C2452' { $find = 'hello'; $replace = 'again' }
        # etcetera etcetera..
    }
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer -ScriptBlock {
        # -replace uses regex, so the $findThis string needs to be escaped because it may or may not
        # contain characters that have special meaning in Regular Expressions.
        (Get-Content -Path 'C:\test\test.ini' -Raw) -replace [regex]::Escape($using:find), $using:replace | Set-Content -Path 'C:\test\test.ini'
    }
}
```